# How to make a Flutter web page scrollable with go_router?

Tags: flutter

I have a webpage built with go_router package.  There is a ShellRoute to make a header image and header navigation bar static to all pages.  I am not able to make the page vertically scrollable but was given rendering issue, no matter where I put the SingleChildScrollView (at the same time remove the Expanded).

Here are the codes:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:go_router/go_router.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

final GoRouter _router = GoRouter(
  initialLocation: '/',
  routes: [
    ShellRoute(
      builder: (context, state, child) {
        return Scaffold(
          body: Padding(
            padding:EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 200),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Image.asset('images/Banner.png'), //header image
                Container( //header menu
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  height: 100,
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: child,
                ),
              ]
            ),
          ),
          );
      },
      routes: [
        GoRoute(
          path: "/",
          builder: (context, state) {
            return HomePage();
          },
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ],
);

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp.router(
      routerConfig: _router,
      title: 'Test',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  /// Constructs a [HomeScreen]
  HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('hit');
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
            children: [
              Container(height: 200, color: Colors.purple),
              Container(height: 300, color: Colors.green),
              Container(height: 400, color: Colors.red),
            ]
          )
        );
  }
}
```

Another interesting thing is, the class HomePage is fired 3 times on every hot restart.  If there is network activity like loading data from api, it will fire 3 times that makes the loading time 3 times longer.

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to wrap the column in your `HomePage` with a `SingleChildScrollView`, so like

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  /// Constructs a [HomeScreen]
  HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('hit');
    return Scaffold(
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
              children: [
                Container(height: 200, color: Colors.purple),
                Container(height: 300, color: Colors.green),
                Container(height: 400, color: Colors.red),
              ]
          ),
        )
    );
  }
}
```

The `Expanded` should NOT be removed.

About the rebuilding. Not sure why it happens multiple times but it shouldn't be an issue. You should never do any fetching from api in your build method anyway. You should always implement your `build` method in such a way that multiple callings to it has no side effects. Like usually you have a `StatefulWidget` and then you do the api call in the `initState`, not in the `build`

Comment: Thanks Ivo, I should have put the header inside the HomePage (and include in every other pages) instead of putting in ShellRoute.  Thanks for inspiring.